# Send HTML file in Apache Camel RouteBuilder

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am having HTML file which I want to send as a response for the rest call inside Apache camel RouteBuilder. The code looks like below

```
public class RestEndpointRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {

        rest("/form")
                .post()
                .produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
                .to("file:target/classes/static/form.html");
    }
```

But, I am getting below error when I call the API

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot write null body to file: target\classes\static\form.html\ID-*****-***-****
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:245)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:277)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:165)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:79)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
```

Basically, I want to return an HTML file, which is a ReactJS application, alongwith JS minified files. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: the api say theres is not body, use .log("${body}") to watch the body you got before .to()

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code:

1. The more appropriate HTTP method is rather `GET` instead of `POST`
2. The file component here is a `to` endpoint so it is used as a **producer**, in other words, it will **save** into the file instead of reading it as you expect.
3. The URI of the file component is incorrect, the URI format is `file:directoryName[?options]` which means that `target/classes/static/form.html` is supposed to be a directory, not a file.

What you try to achieve could be done as follow:

```
rest("/form")
    // Fix #1: Use "get" instead of "post"
    .get() 
    .produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    .to("direct:fileContent");

from("direct:fileContent")
     // Fix #2: Use "pollEnrich" to use the file component as a 
     // consumer to read the file
     // Fix #3: Fix the URI to have the directory name on one side  
     // and the file name on the other side
    .pollEnrich("file:target/classes/static?fileName=form.html");
```

**NB:** Even if what I described above will work, please note that a rest endpoint is not meant to be used for static content, **you are supposed to use a reverse proxy instead**.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: Which version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Currently it's 2.19.1

Comment: This is much too old (+5 years), you should really switch to a more recent version